# Optimising transition state geometries using gaussian 16

Tags: optimization, computational-chemistry

I'm attempting to carry out transition state optimisations in Gaussian and a lot of my calculations are coming up with errors, the main one being

> no analytic 2nd derivatives for this method.

How can I get past this?
I am using the same input as for the local minima, but using the statement `opt=(ts,noeigen,calcfc)`
Am I perhaps missing something?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: This may be more appropriate on [Matter Modeling SE](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/). You will need to include your input file and ideally also the exact error message(s) you are getting in the output. `calcfc` computes analytic second derivatives, so if the dft functional you are using doesn't have these, it won't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Tyberius thank you, sorry my question was so bad and in the wrong place, I’m completely new here - kind of disheartening to see a down vote to be honest!! I’m not trying to be annoying. I think replacing the calcfc with estmfc has worked. 
Thanks for your help, I’ll know in future:)

Comment: No worries, not my downvote. I think you could either request the question be migrated to Matter Modeling or delete the question here and repost it there. I'm a mod there and we have a very low tendency for downvoting, especially new users.